How to add Enable Objects system configuration in magento 2.4.6
Select objects to log actions when any admin users perform in the backend how to do?

system.xml

    <?xml version="1.0"?>

       <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
   <system>
    <tab id="vendor" translate="label" class="vendor" sortOrder="800">
        <label>Vendor Extensions</label>
    </tab>  
    <section id="vendor_module" translate="label" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Admin Action Log</label>
        <tab>vendor</tab>
        <resource>Vendor_Module::config</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>General Configuration</label>
            <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Enabled</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="clear_action_logs_days" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Automatically Clear Action Logs after ... Days</label>
                <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
            </field>
            <field id="enable_objects" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="110" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Enable Objects</label>
                 <source_model>vendor\module\Model\Config\Source\Options</source_model>
                <!--frontend_model>vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Checkboxes</frontend_model-->
               
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>



as far as I understood, you want to pass the values of the "Enable Objects" shown in the screenshot given of the backend. To do so, need to pass those options in the toOptionsArray method. Your Options.php code should be like below.
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

class Options implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = array();

        $options = [
            [
                'value' => 'catalog_products',
                'label' => 'Catalog Products'
            ],
            [
                'value' => 'catalog_categories',
                'label' => 'Catalog Categories'
            ],
            ...
        ];
        
        return $options;
    }
}

